# How do I reach my application from gunicorn's pre_fork hook?

Tags: python, gunicorn, cherrypy

I'm using CherryPy with gunicorn and I need to have my application instance run its **init** on the main thread pre-fork and run some other method post-fork (assume I have a good reason - as I do). I can install a post_fork hook, but I can't see how I reach my application instance to call the method.

```py
import logging

bind = '0.0.0.0:80'
workers = 3
preload_app = True
logconfig = 'logging.conf'


def post_fork(server, worker):
    logging.info('server:%s worker:%s', server, worker) 
    # How to I reach #2 in server.Server.start?   <-------- #1
```

```py
import logging

import cherrypy


class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        # I need to run pre-fork
        logging.info('init')

    def start(self):
        # I need to be called post-fork  <-------- #2
        logging.info('start')

    @cherrypy.expose
    def test(self):
        return "ok"


application = cherrypy.Application(Server(), config={"global": {"environment": "embedded"}}
```

```
$ gunicorn -c config.py server:application
2019-08-14 00:42:26,033:22541:MainThread:INFO: init
2019-08-14 00:42:26,033:22541:MainThread:INFO: Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-08-14 00:42:26,033:22541:MainThread:INFO: Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (22541)
2019-08-14 00:42:26,033:22541:MainThread:INFO: Using worker: sync
2019-08-14 00:42:26,038:22544:MainThread:INFO: Booting worker with pid: 22544
2019-08-14 00:42:26,040:22544:MainThread:INFO: server:<gunicorn.arbiter.Arbiter object at 0x108f8efd0> worker:<Worker 22544>
2019-08-14 00:42:26,131:22545:MainThread:INFO: Booting worker with pid: 22545
2019-08-14 00:42:26,133:22545:MainThread:INFO: server:<gunicorn.arbiter.Arbiter object at 0x108f8efd0> worker:<Worker 22545>
2019-08-14 00:42:26,156:22546:MainThread:INFO: Booting worker with pid: 22546
2019-08-14 00:42:26,157:22546:MainThread:INFO: server:<gunicorn.arbiter.Arbiter object at 0x108f8efd0> worker:<Worker 22546>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit more playing, I've found the answer:

```py
def post_fork(server, worker):
    worker.app.callable.root.start()
```

Comment: I'd be useful if you explained it and marked this answer as a solution...

Comment: how did you initialise the class pre_fork?

Comment: @geher the last line in the sample code initialises the class, with the `Server()`.

Comment: @webKnjaZ I'm not sure how to explain it other than that is the path from worker to the root class. It just wasn't well documented or obvious without inspecting the contents of worker, app, and then callable. Once I added copious debug for the contents of each layer, I found my root instance there.